# Emulator rounds off latitude and longitude to 4 decimal places

Tags: android, google-maps

The latitude and longitude reported in the emulator don't match the precision of the values I send.

I noticed this when a particular lat/lng I was using showed ocean.

How can I get a better precision?

[image: Latitude and Longitude rounded off to 4 decimal places]

Comment: Where is  the code?

Comment: What code? I enter the values into the window, press "SEND", and the values in the "Currently reported location" are rounded off.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that even though the values displayed in 'Currently reported location' are rounded to 4 decimal places - the actual Location values received (using fused provider with emulator) are as entered to at least the 6th decimal place:

[image]

and log of Location:

```
onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422435,-122.084330 hAcc=23 et=+6d18h26m58s725ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]
```

Perhaps collecting more data and posting will help locate your issue.

Furthermore, even rounding to the 4th decimal place should incur at worst 11 meters of error.

What's interesting though is at that precision of 6 decimal places, it can take a full minute for the value to lock in after sending one position update with the emulator - here the previous position latitude was 37.422730 and in the emulator a position with latitude of 37.422234 was sent:

```
  04-26 01:48:32.761 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422730,-122.084330 hAcc=15 et=+6d18h39m43s985ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:48:34.814 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422568,-122.084330 hAcc=13 et=+6d18h39m48s986ms alt=0.0 vAcc=27 sAcc=??? 
  04-26 01:48:42.846 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422422,-122.084330 hAcc=14 et=+6d18h39m54s56ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:48:44.890 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422322,-122.084330 hAcc=13 et=+6d18h39m59s71ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:48:52.849 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422305,-122.084330 hAcc=14 et=+6d18h40m4s89ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:48:54.921 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422267,-122.084330 hAcc=13 et=+6d18h40m9s116ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:02.908 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422261,-122.084330 hAcc=14 et=+6d18h40m14s143ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:05.006 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422246,-122.084330 hAcc=13 et=+6d18h40m19s177ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:12.982 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422244,-122.084330 hAcc=14 et=+6d18h40m24s193ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:15.010 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422238,-122.084330 hAcc=13 et=+6d18h40m29s230ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:23.037 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422237,-122.084330 hAcc=14 et=+6d18h40m34s259ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:25.072 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422235,-122.084330 hAcc=13 et=+6d18h40m39s275ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:33.079 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422235,-122.084330 hAcc=14 et=+6d18h40m44s302ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
  04-26 01:49:35.135 3232-3232/ onLocationChanged: Location[fused 37.422234,-122.084330 hAcc=13 et=+6d18h40m49s319ms vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]
```

This apparently is a function of the fused provider doing some bit of smoothing or averaging.

Tried this on a Nexus 5 and Pixel 2 emulator with same results.